SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 Unable to parse: use DB_Name;
I'm encountering an error while trying to connect to a MariaDB cluster using a load balancer IP in my Laravel application. The error message is:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 Unable to parse: use DB_Name;
Interestingly, I can connect to the same MariaDB instance using a standalone PHP script without any issues.
Here is the relevant configuration from my config/database.php file:
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST_MYSQL', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT_MYSQL', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_MYSQL', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_MYSQL', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_MYSQL', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
    ]) : [],
],

Additional Information The connection works fine with a standalone PHP script. The issue seems to be specific to the Laravel application.
What I've Tried Verified that the .env file has the correct database connection settings. Cleared the configuration cache using PHP artisan config:cache. Checked the SQL modes in MariaDB to ensure they are compatible. Tested the database connection using Laravel's Tinker. Logged SQL queries to identify the problematic query.

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 Unable to parse: use DB_Name; I think that there is a variable which must be initialized with some value, and the value  DB_Name is used as a placeholder, but you do not alter this, and the command is provided with this placeholder value which causes the error. Find the place where you'd set the value, and provide according database name.

Yes, I am using my actual database name in place of this placeholder

Are you using ProxySQL ?

Yes, this MariaDB instance is hosted behind a load balancer, and I am using the load balancer's IP address as the hostname. When I attempt to connect to the MariaDB instance from the server terminal, the connection works without any issues.
